# Tkinter Entry StringVars can't be edited from inside a thread if they have been placed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI written in `tkinter`. After switching some of the elements from the `grid()` method to the `place()` method, I get an error `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop` and my entire GUI freezes. [this github](https://github.com/whatwareweb/homebase/blob/dev/homebase.py) has code that worked before, and doesn't work now. I don't know why I'm getting this error, I have not changed anything relating to editing the `StringVar`s.

````py
# GUI code.

hourText = Label(timerFrame, text='Hours', bg=themebg, fg=themefg)
minuteText = Label(timerFrame, text='Minutes', bg=themebg, fg=themefg)
secondText = Label(timerFrame, text='Seconds', bg=themebg, fg=themefg)
hourEntry = Entry(timerFrame, width=3, font=("Arial", 18, ""), textvariable=hour, bg=themebg, fg=themefg,
                  insertbackground=themefg)
minuteEntry = Entry(timerFrame, width=3, font=("Arial", 18, ""), textvariable=minute, bg=themebg, fg=themefg,
                    insertbackground=themefg)
secondEntry = Entry(timerFrame, width=3, font=("Arial", 18, ""), textvariable=second, bg=themebg, fg=themefg,
                    insertbackground=themefg)
timerPauseButton = Button(timerFrame, text='Pause', command=timerPause, bg=themebg, fg=themefg)
timerSubmit = Button(timerFrame, text='Start', command=submit, bg='blue')
toHome = Button(timerFrame, text='Home', command=returnHome, bg='green')
hourText.place(x=65, y=0, width=50, height=20)
minuteText.place(x=110, y=0, width=50, height=20)
secondText.place(x=160, y=0, width=50, height=20)
hourEntry.place(x=65, y=25, width=50, height=40)
minuteEntry.place(x=110, y=25, width=50, height=40)
secondEntry.place(x=160, y=25, width=50, height=40)
timerSubmit.place(x=135, y=65, width=75, height=30)
timerPauseButton.place(x=65, y=65, width=75, height=30)
toHome.place(x=110, y=95, width=50, height=30)


# Editing the StringVar.

def timerloop():
    global pauseState
    try:
        temp = int(hour.get()) * 3600 + int(minute.get()) * 60 + int(second.get())
    except:
        return

    while temp > -1 and pauseState != 1:
        mins, secs = divmod(temp, 60)
        hours = 0
        if mins > 60:
            hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        hour.set("{0:2d}".format(hours))
        minute.set("{0:2d}".format(mins))
        second.set("{0:2d}".format(secs))
        time.sleep(1)
        if temp == 0 and pauseState == 0:
            hour.set('')
            minute.set('')
            second.set('')
            notification.notify(
                title="Homebase",
                app_icon="logo.ico" if platform.system().lower() == 'windows' else 'logo.gif',
                message="Time is up.",
                timeout=10
            )
            sound = AudioSegment.from_file(str(alarmEntryText.get()))
            play(sound)
            pauseState = None
            exit()
        if pauseState == 0:
            temp -= 1
        if pauseState == 2:
            temp = 0


# Creating the thread.

def submit():
    if hour.get() == '':
        hour.set('0')
    if minute.get() == '':
        minute.set('0')
    if second.get() == '':
        second.set('0')
    global pauseState
    if pauseState == 1:
        pauseState = 0
    if pauseState is not None:
        timerStop()
        timerSubmit['text'] = 'Start'
        timerSubmit['bg'] = 'blue'
    else:
        timerSubmit['text'] = 'Stop'
        timerSubmit['bg'] = 'red'
        timerthread = Thread(target=timerloop)
        timerthread.start()```
````

Comment: The error is because `tkinter` doesn't support multithreading in the sense that only one thread in a multithreaded program can interact with it — that's what the error message means. It has nothing directly to do with switching from `grid()` to `place()`. There are many questions here about this issue with answers specifying how to work around it.

Comment: but it worked fine with `grid()`, and i thought the python 3.x versions of tkinter supported it

Comment: many GUIs don't like to run in threads and all widgets have to be used/changed in main thread. Other elements may run in separated thread - but they have to send information to main thread to change widgets.

Comment: @kidney: When something isn't "thread-safe" like `tkinter`, it means that using it with them can cause unpredictable behaviour, like crashing for mysterious reasons for seemingly unrelated reasons, to occur.

Comment: See the [description](https://github.com/abarnert/mttkinter#readme) in the `READEME.md` file of the `mttkinter` module for a good explanation.